# Hide "Submit"/"Save" button until file has finished uploading

Tags: ajax, javascript, files

I'm having a problem where my site users are submitting a form before the files they are uploading into filefield are finished, this is causing an ajax error to pop up along the lines of "**an ajax HTTP request terminated abnormally**".

To stop this mistake from happening is there a way to hide the **"Submit"/"Save"** button until file has finished uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Havent tried this, but you might be able to use jquery's [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), to hide the submit button, in particular the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` handlers. Something like the following, added in a .js file in a custom module (not tested):

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = {
   attach: function (context) {
     $(document).ajaxStart(function(e){
       $('#edit-submit').hide();
     });
     $(docment).ajaxComplete(function(e){
       $('#edit-submit').show();
     });
   }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You'd have to edit that to work the way you need it to, save it in a js file, and [add it to the node edit form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1253520) (or any other form you need it for).

Aside from that, the "ajax HTTP request terminated abnormally" errors occur in D7 whenever a http request is made before an ajax request has completed. In my opinion this is undesirable behaviour. It's been discussed [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416), for example, and the [prevent js alerts module](https://www.drupal.org/project/prevent_js_alerts) suppresses such errors across your site.

Comment: I think you should only use Drupal.behaviors.*.attach, if you then also use the "context" variable in your selector. In this case, you are attaching a behavior to the document root, so you do not need Drupal.behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
$('#edit-submit').bind('click',function() {
    $('#edit-submit').hide();
    $.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.life_style.secure_base_url+'path_to_form',
    data: data,
    type:'POST',
    async:true,
    cache:true,
    success: function(result) {
        //
        $('#edit-submit').show();
    },
         dataType: "html"
});
```

}